# Multiprocessing backed parallel loops cannot be nested below threads

Tags: scikit-learn, python-multithreading, joblib

What is the reason of such issue in joblib?
'Multiprocessing backed parallel loops cannot be nested below threads, setting n_jobs=1'
What should I do to avoid such issue?

Actually I need to implement XMLRPC server which run heavy computation in background thread and report current progress through polling from UI client. It uses scikit-learn which are based on joblib.

P.S.:
I've simply changed name of the thread to "MainThread" to avoid such warning and everything looks working good (run in parallel as expected without issues). What might be a problem in future for such workaround?

Comment: As far as I understand, the problem is that one of your threads spawns another multithreaded computation. I, personally, don't see a need for that (yes, you can use complex fork model, but why do you use parallel loops for that?) since, presumably, you're already utilizing all parallelism you have.

Comment: I am getting a very similar error but with multiprocessing instead of threading: `Loky-backed parallel loops cannot be called in a multiprocessing, setting n_jobs=1`. Does anybody know a solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same warning while doing predictions with sklearn within a thread, using a model I loaded and which was fitted with n_jobs > 1. It appears when you pickle a model it is saved with its parameters, including n_jobs.

To avoid the warning (and potential serialization cost), set n_jobs to 1 when pickling your models:

```
clf = joblib.load(model_filename).set_params(n_jobs=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be due to this [issue](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/180) in JobLib library. At the moment of writing this seems to be fixed but not released yet. As written in the question, a dirty fix would to rename the main thread back to `MainThread`:

`threading.current_thread().name = 'MainThread'`

Comment: Where do you call this? It has no effect for me.

Comment: @Cerin right before I initialise and fit the classifier .

Comment: This also had no effect for me.

Comment: I've just noticed that the issue started to pop up again after I upgraded some libs. Looks like the behaviour got changed.

Comment: Any updates? I also noticed the behavior chanced when updating libraries